# Different view depending on modelproperty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Have been stuck with an problem for a while now, so hoping to get some help here.

I have made an tv-guide that consist of 5 different views, ChannelOne, ChannelTwo, ChannelThree, ChannelFour and one that show All four channels(fullView). I have 5 tables for this and by entity framework made 5 corresponding models, with this properties(they are similar for the other 4 models):

```
public partial class ChannelOne
{
    public int Id_ChannelOne_ { get; set; }
    public string Channel_ChannelOne_ { get; set; }
    public string Program_ChannelOne_ { get; set; }
    public string Date_ChannelOne_ { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> Time_ChannelOne_ { get; set; }
}
```

When I click at a program in my fullView I want to go the view that correspond to that program (the view of that specific channel).

if I have an actionlink for this to get back to my control for my fullView,

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Go to channel", "Index", new { channel = item.Channel })
```

how can I there decide which view to go to depending on my channel property?

I want something like this:

```
private TvProgramDBEntities db = new TvProgramDBEntities();
 
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string channel)
    {
        if (channel == "ChannelOne")
            return View(db.ChannelOne);
        if (channel == "ChannelTwo")
            return View(db.ChannelTwo);
    }
                 .
                 .
                 .
```

Comment: Create controller for each channels, then just use `return RedirectToAction("ChannelOne")` and set the channel selection action as `[HttpGet]` - because `ActionLink` uses GET method.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Thx for input Tetsuya, but how does the controller now when to redirect me to ChannelOne? (need to redirect to the right view depending on what my channel propertie are) Or are i missing something? @Tetsuya

Answer (score 0):

Mvc will look up a view when you use the Html.DisplayFor and Html.EditorFor template helpders inside a main view.

E.g.

```
/Views/Channel
    /DisplayTemplates
        ChannelOne.cshtml
   Index.cshtml
```

With a model like

```
public class ChannelViewer
{
    public object Channel {get;set;}
}
```

So you could have in index.cshtml

```
@model ChannelModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Channel)
```

This would look up the correct view from the displaytemplates folder.  This will search the current controllers folder, then the shared display templates folder.

You can do the same with the EditorTemplates.  You can tailor each view to the different channels then.